# How to save Weekly Weather Forecast data in MongoDB using the Mongoose model with weather API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, weather-api, mongoose-models

How to save Weekly Weather Forecast data in MongoDB using the Mongoose model?

I'm a beginner and as my first mini-project, I'm writing an app for getting weekly weather forecast data from OpenWeatherApi. The issue I'm facing is that the Api I'm using returns the weather forecast for 7 days every 3 hours. the Json file would be like this:

```
"list": [
        {
            "dt": 1684746000,
            "main": {
                "temp": 300.84,
                "feels_like": 300.03,
                "temp_min": 300.84,
                "temp_max": 301.69,
                "pressure": 1021,
                "sea_level": 1021,
                "grnd_level": 853,
                "humidity": 30,
                "temp_kf": -0.85
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 75
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 0.66,
                "deg": 278,
                "gust": 2.33
            },
            "visibility": 10000,
            "pop": 0,
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2023-05-22 09:00:00"
        },
```

in the dt_text part as you can see I have the date + the hour. the json file includes 40 results like the above for every 3 hours.

I want to save this data in my Database. The mongoose model I wrote is as below:

```
const dailyWeatherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  dt: String,
  dt_text: String,
  city: {
    type: String,
    name: String,
    country: String,
    unique: true,
  },
  main: {
    temp: Number,
    feels_like: Number,
    temp_min: Number,
    temp_max: Number,
    humidity: Number,
  },
  weather: [
    {
      main: String,
      description: String,
    },
  ],
});

const weeklyWeatherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  weekStartDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  monday: dailyWeatherSchema,
  tuesday: dailyWeatherSchema,
  wednesday: dailyWeatherSchema,
  thursday: dailyWeatherSchema,
  friday: dailyWeatherSchema,
  saturday: dailyWeatherSchema,
  sunday: dailyWeatherSchema,
});

const WeeklyWeather = mongoose.model(
  'Weekly Weather',
  weeklyWeatherSchema
);

module.exports = WeeklyWeather
```

I want to save data for each day only at 09:00 am but I got stuck in the first part. the data won't save in my dataBase.

my controller is as belowe:

```
app.get('/weatherg/:city', async (req, res) => {
  let city = req.params.city;
  console.log(city);

  await axios
    .get(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&&appid=${API_KEY}`
    )
    .then(async (response) => {
      const newForcastData = await response.data;

      console.log(newForcastData);
      await new Forcast(newForcastData).save();
    });
```

I got the data from "newForcastData" part but the data won't save in database. I get the below err:

```
   this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);
                               ^

ValidationError: Weekly Weather validation failed: weekStartDate: Path `weekStartDate` is required.
```

So Here are my questions in summary:

1. How to filter the data only to show data that have the 09:00 part?
2. Why I get the err with my Mongoose model :(
3. how to change the "dt" part so the data will save with day name in dataBase.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.